# Sylius lost configuration after a form submit

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I'm trying to make a dynamic menu based on one entity MenuItem which can have one parent and children.
I use this configuration :

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        app.menu_item:
            classes:
                model: App\Infrastructure\Doctrine\Entity\Menu\DoctrineMenuItem
                repository: App\Infrastructure\Doctrine\Repository\DoctrineMenuItemRepository
                factory: App\Infrastructure\Factory\Menu\MenuItemFactory
                form: App\Infrastructure\Form\Admin\Menu\MenuItemType
```

```
sylius_grid:
    grids:
        app_admin_menu_item:
            driver:
                name: doctrine/orm
                options:
                    class: App\Infrastructure\Doctrine\Entity\Menu\DoctrineMenuItem
                    repository:
                        method: getFirstLevelItemsQB
```

```
sylius_grid:
    grids:
        app_admin_menu_group:
            driver:
                name: doctrine/orm
                options:
                    class: App\Infrastructure\Doctrine\Entity\Menu\DoctrineMenuItem
                    repository:
                        method: getGroupsByParentIdQB
                        arguments:
                            parentId: $parentId
```

```
app_admin_menu_item:
    resource: |
        alias: app.menu_item
        section: admin
        templates: "@SyliusAdmin\\Crud"
        redirect: index
        grid: app_admin_menu_item
        permission: true
        vars:
            index:
                icon: list
    type: sylius.resource

app_admin_menu_item_index:
    path: /
    methods: [GET]
    defaults:
        _controller: app.controller.menu_item:indexAction
        _sylius:
            repository:
                method: getFirstLevelItemList
            template: "@SyliusAdmin/Crud/index.html.twig"
            grid: app_admin_menu_item
            section: admin
            permission: true
```

```
app_admin_group_create:
    path: /new
    methods: [GET, POST]
    defaults:
        _controller: app.controller.menu_item:createAction
        _sylius:
            section: admin
            permission: true
            template: "@SyliusAdmin/Crud/create.html.twig"
            redirect:
                route: app_admin_group_index
                parameters: { parentId: $parentId }
            factory:
                method: createGroup
                arguments:
                    - expr:notFoundOnNull(service('app.repository.menu_item').find($parentId))
            vars:
                route:
                    parameters:
                        parentId: $parentId
```

```
class MenuItemType extends AbstractType
{
    private MenuItemRepository $repository;
    private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(
        MenuItemRepository $repository,
        UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator
    )
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('alias', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'app.grid.menu.fields.alias',
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('link', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'app.grid.menu.fields.link',
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('taxon', TaxonAutocompleteChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => 'app.grid.menu.fields.taxon',
                'required' => false
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => DoctrineMenuItem::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I submit the form for the menu group item, Sylius lost the configuration (for the factory in particular) and get the configuration of the parent. And so the object return by the factory after form submission is not the one I expected.

This problem happens when I'm trying to override the default FormType, without it, it works fine.

Any possibility to force him to use the right configuration?

Comment: Can you show the resource definitions?
Also, why did you add that extension on DefaultResourceType with an if, instead of setting the form type in the resource definition or in the route configuration?

Comment: Just add the resource definittions. And for the extension, it's just because I don't know that I can do it the way you described. Will look to change this.